# can you use getattr to call a function within your scope?

Tags: python, getattr

I'm trying to do something like this, but I can't figure out how to call the function `bar`.

```
def foo():
    def bar(baz):
        print('used getattr to call', baz)
    getattr(bar, __call__())('bar')

foo()
```

Notice, that this is somewhat unusual. Normally you'd have an object and get an attribute on that, which could be a function. then it's easy to run. but what if you just have a function within the current scope - how to do getattr on the current scope to run the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. To use `getattr`, pass the string value of the [name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) of the attribute:

```
getattr(bar, "__call__")('bar')
```

i.e

```
def foo():
  def bar(baz):
    print('used getattr to call', baz)
  getattr(bar, "__call__")('bar')

foo()
```

Output:

```
used getattr to call bar
```

Comment: what if I wanted to do `getattr('bar', "__call__")('bar')` ? when I try to make the function referenced via a string I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__call__'` Is there any way to reference the name of that dynamically?

Comment: I just used a map, this works for my purposes `methods = {'bar': bar} ; getattr(methods['bar']...`

Comment: just call the `locals()` function, it returns a dictionary of objects from the local scope

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, you can also use the [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#locals) function which returns a dict of local symbols:

```
def foo():
  def bar(baz):
    print('used getattr to call', baz)
  locals()['bar']('pouet')

foo()
```

It also allows you to get the function by its name instead of its reference without need for a custom mapping.